# Getting Issues In Adding A Tab Using AWK

Tags: linux, awk, sed, apache-pig, bigdata

**Sample Logs**

```
Location        Number  Status  Comment
Delhi           919xxx  Processed       Test File 1
Mumbai          918xxx  Got Stucked     Test File 123
```

I'm trying to add one tab space after **Status** using **AWK**, but getting error.

**Sample Query**

```
awk '{$3 = $3 "\t"; print}' z
```

**Getting Output As**

```
Location Number Status   Comment
Delhi 919xxx Processed   Test File 1
Mumbai 918xxx **Got**        **Stucked** Test File 123
```

As it is taking 'Got Stucked' as multiple fields please suggest.

Comment: I've probably changed the input file somewhat in my editing; but if it's got a 2+ character separator between the fields, then you could get by with some sed, rather than awk

Comment: How can a script tell that the space in `Got Stucked` is part of a field instead of a separator between fields? Are your fields actually separated by tabs or are your fields fixed width or something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want one tab after the header text `Status` to make it look better, use `sub` to the first record only:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {sub(/Status/,"Status\t")} 1' file
Location        Number  Status              Comment
Delhi           919xxx  Processed           Test File 1
Mumbai          918xxx  Got Stucked         Test File 123
```

This way awk won't rebuild the record and replace `FS` with `OFS` etc.

Answer (score 2):

@JamesBrown's answer sounds like what you asked for but also consider:

```
$ awk -F'  +' -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1}1' file | column -s$'\t' -t
Location  Number  Status       Comment
Delhi     919xxx  Processed    Test File 1
Mumbai    918xxx  Got Stucked  Test File 123
```

The awk converts every sequence of 2+ spaces to a tab so the result is a tab-separated stream which `column` can then convert to a visually aligned table if that's your ultimate goal. Or you could generate a CSV to read into Excel or similar:

```
$ awk -F'  +' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1' file
Location,Number,Status,Comment
Delhi,919xxx,Processed,Test File 1
Mumbai,918xxx,Got Stucked,Test File 123

$ awk -F'  +' -v OFS=',' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i="\""$i"\""}1' file
"Location","Number","Status","Comment"
"Delhi","919xxx","Processed","Test File 1"
"Mumbai","918xxx","Got Stucked","Test File 123"
```

or more robustly:

```
$ awk -F'  +' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { gsub(/"/,"\"\"",$i); if ($i~/[[:space:],"]/) $i="\""$i"\"" } }1' file
Location,Number,Status,Comment
Delhi,919xxx,Processed,"Test File 1"
Mumbai,918xxx,"Got Stucked","Test File 123"
```

If your input fields aren't always separated by at least 2 blank chars then tell us how they are separated.

Comment: That should probably be 2+ spaces or tab.

Comment: Could be, in which case `-F'[[:space:]]{2,}|\t'`. Could be it's fixed width input too, idk. I'm hoping for some response from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
awk -F'  ' '{$3 = $3 "\t"; print}' z
```

The problem is that awk consider (by default) a single space as the separator between two column. This means that `Got Stucked` are actually two different columns.

With `-F'  '` you tell awk to use a double space as the separator to distinguish between two columns.